# How to insert data into two tables simultaneously in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables, vehicle and vehicle_type. I want to add same data into both tables using one form. How can i do this?

Comment: If you have to insert same data in 2 different table, you database model is certainly wrong... ;)

You cannot do two successive `INSERT INTO ... ` queries ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a form in SQL. So extend your tags to indicate what you are developing in.

Comment: You may be able to perform both inserts in a transaction, but standard SQL's `INSERT` statement (and `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc) can only affect *one* table. So you'll need two statements or to be using product specific extensions to the language (if they exist)

Comment: IF YOU want that to happen every time a record is inserted in one table should go in other table, Just use trigger. It will be straight forward.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? And why do you want to do that? Are you trying to access a generated ID for the `vehicle_type` table? If yes, then there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create stored procedure with parameters.

Inside the stored procedure called 2 insert into statement with parameters as the values.

With stored procedure you could have transaction control - rollback the insert for both tables if there is any error.

```
create procedure insert_into_2_tables
@column1 varchar(50),
@column2 int,
...

as

begin tran

insert into table1 values (@column1, @column2, ...)

insert into table2 values (@column1, @column2, ...)

if @@error <> 0
  rollback tran
else commit tran
```

-- you can call this stored procedure from your form, code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Write two separate insert statements for inserting the data into both vehicle and vehicle type tables.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specfiy your DBMS, but in Postgres you can do this with a single SQL statement:

```
with new_type as (
   insert into vehicle_type values (1, 'big')
   returning id
)
insert into vehicle
values
(1, (select id from new_type), 'super model');
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9051c/1